How to handle touch event for parent and child views in Android
I am trying to implement drag-and-drop functionality in my app using the DragLinearLayout class. I have successfully implemented the drag-and-drop feature. Now, I want to enable drag-and-drop when the user long-presses the layout and also add a delete button to each layout when drag-and-drop is enabled.
To achieve this, I read the views when the user long-presses the layout, place each layout inside a FrameLayout, add a close button to the FrameLayout, and then place the FrameLayout inside DragLinearLayout. However, I am facing an issue. I cannot drag the view when I add the FrameLayout. After intercepting the touch events for the FrameLayout, I can perform drag-and-drop, but I cannot click the close button. I have overridden the onTouch event for the close button as well, but it is not working.
What can I try next?
private void doLongPressProcess() {

        for (int i = 0; i < dragLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View child = dragLayout.getChildAt(i);
            child.setId(View.generateViewId());
            child.setTag("" + i);
            FrameLayout childFrame = getFrameLayout(i);

            dragLayout.removeViewAt(i);
            childFrame.addView(child);
            dragLayout.addView(childFrame, i);

            if (i != 0 && i != 2) {
//To enable drag and drop only for 0 and 2nd position
                dragLayout.setViewDraggable(childFrame, childFrame);
                ImageView closeButton = getImageView(child, dragLayout);
                (childFrame).addView(closeButton);
            } else {
                dragLayout.disableViewDraggable(child, child);
            }
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    private FrameLayout getFrameLayout(int i) {

        FrameLayout childFrame = new FrameLayout(context) {

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        childFrame.setTag("Frame" + i);
        childFrame.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,
                WRAP_CONTENT));
        GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
        border.setStroke(1, Color.BLACK); //black border with full opacity
        childFrame.setBackground(border);
        return childFrame;
    }


    @NonNull
    private ImageView getImageView(View child, dragLayout dragLayout) {
        ImageView closeButton = new androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView(context) {

            @Override
            public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener l) {
                super.setOnTouchListener(l);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Notify parent that child might handle the click
                        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Handle the click event
                        performClick();
                        // Notify parent that child has handled the click
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        // Cancel the click handling
                        break;
                }
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        closeButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
        closeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close);
        closeButton.setTag(child.getTag());
        closeButton.setY(0);
        closeButton.setX(0);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int size = dragLayout.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                if (dragLayout.getChildAt(i).getTag().equals(v.getTag())) {
                    dragLayout.removeViewInLayout(dragLayout.getChildAt(i));
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return closeButton;
    }


SIde note but Android is Kotlin first: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first and Compose recommended: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose

Finally, capture the view at the x and y position when the button is clicked, and handle the actions based on the captured view.
public boolean isCloseButton(int x, int y, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (isCloseButton(x, y, ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i), viewGroup)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else if (view instanceof CustomImageView) {
            if (x > view.getLeft() && x < view.getRight() && y > view.getTop() && y < view.getBottom()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

